# How to create custom 404 error page in cake 3?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am working on cake 3 project.

I want to create custom 404 error page for all cake errors like missing controller, method, template or others errors.

I want to show custom 404 error page for these all errors,
but I don't have a clue.

Please let me know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just create a 404.ctp file in the src\Error\ folder of your app

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the existing .ctp files in /src/Template/Error directory of your app

Answer (score 0):

Two steps needed.

**First step:**
You want to change the `app.php` debug mode,
please check this below,

```
/**
* Debug Level:
*
* Production Mode:
* false: No error messages, errors, or warnings shown.
*
* Development Mode:
* true: Errors and warnings shown.
*/
```

**Development mode :** `'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', true), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)`

**Production mode :** `'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', false), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)`

**Second Step:**

Now you need to customize the 404 page design through the error folder `src\Error\`.